# C# - Cursors.Hand.Handle não identifica o cursor " Hand "

Tags: c#, cursor

Eu fiz um programa para identificar se o cursor do mouse é `Hand` ou não. Estou usando um evento que identifica o cursor global, então até mesmo fora do `Form` ele é capaz de identificar. O problema é que na função:

```
private static bool Cursor()
    {
        var h = Cursors.Hand.Handle;

        CURSORINFO pci;
        pci.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CURSORINFO));
        GetCursorInfo(out pci);

        return pci.hCursor == h;
    }
```

Quando eu testo ela em um botão colocando o mouse em cima de algum Link ou outra coisa que torna o cursor `Hand`, ele não identifica! Porém se eu mudar e colocar `Cursors.Default.Handle` ele sempre identifica se o cursor é Default ou não.

O que estou fazendo de errado ? Como identificar se o cursor é `Hand` ou não ?

Comment: Para pegar o cursor atual não é Cursor.Current  ?

Answer (score 0):

Creio que você está pegando o cursor de modo errado,

Tenta assim

```
private static bool Cursor()
    {
        var h = Cursor.Current;

        CURSORINFO pci;
        pci.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CURSORINFO));
        GetCursorInfo(out pci);

        return pci.hCursor == h;
    }
```